# Any changes to Tag-Burnination and Tag-Cleanup in view of there being no "too minor" anymore?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, clean-up, burninate-system

Recently, the ["too minor" rejection-reason was removed for suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039), on account that [every small enhancement counts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239106) and should be accepted (and rejections were not systematic enough).

Now, [the guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191) for [burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) calls for cleaning up all the questions by looking for the bad questions and **not doing minor edits**, but **making the post good enough** (or pruning by CV, DV, delete).

So, does the rejection of "too minor" overthrow the guidance for how burnination works, or does it just highlight the deficits of removing the rejection reason?

If the former, can that really be good for the site?

If the latter, how should a reviewer know the tag is burninated / under active clean-up, and how should he reject too minor edits?

And no, he is not interested in editing those questions, because while he knows enough to spot a too minor "enhancement" on sight, he is not really into that specific muddle of a tag.

Comment: I dispute the assertion in your first paragraph.  I don't think anyone stated that they thought "every small enhancement counts."

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I'm guessing you are only disputing the part "every small enhancement counts". Still, if that's the case, that's not what the community seems to perceive, nor did you dispute that point strongly in the linked questions. At most, you left it hanging, providing no viable alternative (at least yet. Maybe there will be "useless edit" or some such as a rejection-reason later... (Reject and Edit, as pointed out, is not actually viable for that role)). And that was the highest-voted view, so someone should add a better one then.

Comment: My take is that, if you don't want to make the effort to "Accept and Improve" or "Reject and Improve," your alternative is to "Skip."

Comment: Which, considering burnination and clean-up requests, means what exactly? The way I see it, as they are improvements though really minor ones, they will be approved.